# How do I allocate memory with "new" instead of malloc?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

As a homework I have to write a program that operates around structures. As a first task i have to write a function that allocates memory for an array of N pointers that point to new structures(user decides about the value of N) and returns the adress of an array. The first problem that i have is understanding the form of malloc. I asked my professor what would be the equivalent by using "new" because it is more transparent for me but he answered that I should stick to malloc so i avoid making any mistakes. The following function looks like this:

```cpp
struct Structure
{
    int a;
    char b;
    float c;
};

Structure** allocating(int N)
{
    struct Structure** tab = (struct Structure**) malloc(amount * sizeof(struct Structure*));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        tab[i] = (struct Structure*) malloc(sizeof(struct Structure));
    }
    return tab;
}
```

I have tried understanding this form of allocating memory but so far i understand this as if i was allocating memory for a pointer pointing to the array of pointers(double **) which is not what was stated in a task. To sum up, i don't understand the way the allocating is written and how could it be written by using new.

Comment: `(struct Structure**)malloc(amount * sizeof(struct Structure*))` -> `new Structure*[amount];`

Comment: Prefer `std::vector` if you are allowed to use it. If not, strongly consider wrapping your allocation in another structure to [automate its management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii). In general [avoid directly using `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new).

Comment: Do you really have to allocate memory? You could use vectors to avoid the whole task of memory allocation and deallocation. The whole function could be replaced by `std::vector<Structur> allocating(int N) { return std::vector(N); }`.

Comment: "I should stick to malloc so i avoid making any mistakes" literally the opposite advice he/she should have given you. Don't use `malloc`, don't use `new`. Use containers and RAII.

Comment: *I asked my professor what would be the equivalent by using "new" because it is more transparent for me but he answered that I should stick to malloc so i avoid making any mistakes.* Be careful with this. `malloc` has a number of failure case you have to watch for that `new` does not. The big ones are probably 1)  All calls to `malloc` need to be explicitly tested for success while `new` throws an exception on failure, making it much harder to miss. 2) `malloc` does not call constructors and `free` does not call destructors. They can only be used on simple datatypes.

Comment: @user4581301 technically speaking using `malloc` without in-place new is UB as no object is created. It's a whole thing/mess regarding the start of life of objects.

Comment: Agreed. I took placement `new` out of the comment because I was running out of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your C code allocates *an array of pointers to `Structure`*. I have no idea why it is done this way instead of simply allocating *an array of `Structure`*, you have to ask the author of the task for that.

Direct equivalent using `new` would look like this :

```
Structure** allocating(int N)
{
    struct Structure** tab = new Structure*[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        tab[i] = new Structure;
    }
    return tab;
}
```

Deallocating can be a bit tricky:

```
void deallocating(Structure** tab, int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        delete tab[i]; //delete objects
    }
    delete[] tab; //delete array itself, notice the [] after delete!
}
```

If you can move to array of objects instead of array of pointers, the code gets much simpler:

```
Structure* allocating(int N)
{
    return new Structure[N];
}
```

Later you also deallocate it with `delete[]`

---

As noticed in comments, in C++ we prefer to not use memory management directly (especially in modern C++ keyword `new` is considered to be a *bad smell*). `std::vector` can handle all your array-on-the-heap needs perfectly well, it will never leak memory and can resize itself easily.

Comment: `new` may have an odor, but there is more than 2-decades worth of existing codebase that uses it. So well worth knowing.